# Office 365 mailman sending mail: readHandshakeMessages TLS error

Tags: office365, mailman

We are getting problems with some users in our network when sending mails with 365 accounts.
We are using last release of chilkat library and other users have no problems at all.

```
ChilkatLog:
  SendEmail:
    DllDate: Nov 28 2021
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.89
    UnlockPrefix: AGPSFT.CB4022023
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.
    sendEmailInner:
      renderToMime_pt1:
        createEmailForSending:
          Auto-generating Message-ID
        --createEmailForSending
      --renderToMime_pt1
      sendMimeInner:
        ensureSmtpSession:
          ensureSmtpConnection:
            smtpParams:
              SmtpHost: smtp.office365.com
              SmtpPort: 25
              SmtpUsername: noreply@neinorhomes.com
              SmtpSsl: 0
              StartTLS: 0
            --smtpParams
            smtpConnect:
              smtpHostname: smtp.office365.com
              smtpPort: 25
              connectionIsReady:
                Need new SMTP connection
              --connectionIsReady
              smtpSocketConnect:
                socketOptions:
                  SO_SNDBUF: 262144
                  SO_RCVBUF: 4194304
                  TCP_NODELAY: 1
                  SO_KEEPALIVE: 1
                --socketOptions
              --smtpSocketConnect
              smtpGreeting:
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 220 LO4P123CA0489.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 23 Nov 2022 12:33:11 +0000
                --readSmtpResponse
              --smtpGreeting
              ehloCommand:
                sendCmdToSmtp:
                  SmtpCmdSent: EHLO NHPTVA23<CRLF>
                --sendCmdToSmtp
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-LO4P123CA0489.outlook.office365.com Hello [62.87.75.208]
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-SIZE 157286400
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-PIPELINING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-DSN
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-STARTTLS
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-8BITMIME
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-BINARYMIME
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-CHUNKING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250 SMTPUTF8
                --readSmtpResponse
              --ehloCommand
              This SMTP server supports STARTTLS.  Automatically doing STARTTLS...
              If you don't want TLS, set mailman.StartTLSifPossible equal to false (or 0)
              startTLS:
                sendCmdToSmtp:
                  SmtpCmdSent: STARTTLS<CRLF>
                --sendCmdToSmtp
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
                --readSmtpResponse
                clientHandshake:
                  clientHandshake2:
                    ProcessHelloRetryRequest:
                      readHandshakeMessages:
                        Failed to read beginning of SSL/TLS record.
                        b: 0
                        dbSize: 0
                        nReadNBytes: 0
                        idleTimeoutMs: 30000
                      --readHandshakeMessages
                    --ProcessHelloRetryRequest
                  --clientHandshake2
                --clientHandshake
                Client handshake failed. (1)
                connectionClosed: 1
                Failed to establish TLS connection.
              --startTLS
            --smtpConnect
          --ensureSmtpConnection
        --ensureSmtpSession
      --sendMimeInner
    --sendEmailInner
    Failed.
  --SendEmail
--ChilkatLog
```

Windows firewall is disabled, antivirus is Sophos. We've tested different ports (25, 587, etc)
Iread some problems with firewalls but don't know if add aprogram rule or a port one...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from 9.5.0.89 to 9.5.0.93

I believe 9.5.0.93 (released on Nov 18, 2022) contains a fix for this issue.